# Compressed Spring mvc response and decompressed it back in jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, httpresponse

How can I send a spring MVC response in compressed format e.g. gZip form. I will send a json request from jQuery and want a compressed response from spring mvc. after getting the response jQuery should be able to decompressed this response in the required format like JSON. I will be happy if I get a sample.

Comment: That should be configured in the webserver => vote to move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Let the webserver/-browser deal with it. If the webserver gzips the data and sends an appropriate header, the browser will automatically uncompress it.

You have to write **zero** lines of code for this.

Comment: You mean its a default nature ? Do i will have to send the zip format information explicitly for the specific response?